# TestNG Wrong Number of Arguments With DataProviders

Tags: java, excel, testng

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="Suite" parallel="tests" configfailurepolicy="continue" thread-count = "10" verbose="1">
<parameter name="dev" value="true"></parameter>
    <test name ="Chrome" parallel="methods">
        <parameter name="myBrowser" value="chrome" /> 
            <classes>
                <class name="package.TestClass"></class>
                </classes>
            </test>

            <test name ="Firefox" parallel="methods">
        <parameter name="myBrowser" value="firefox" /> 
            <classes>
                <class name="package.TestClass"></class>
                </classes>
            </test>
</suite>
```

In this .xml file I have a parameter named "dev" set to true. I am trying to have my dataproviders read this variable and use a different excel sheet if true.

```
@Parameters("dev")
@DataProvider(parallel = true)
public Object[][] testData(String dev) {
    String path;
    if(dev.equals(true)){
        path =  System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\data\\dev-data.xlsx";
    }
    else{
        path =  System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\data\\reg-data.xlsx";
    }
    ExcelReader reader = new ExcelReader(path);
    Object[][] obj = new Object[reader.getSheetRows("url")][reader.getSheetColumns("url")]; //four test, one argument
    for(int i = 0; i < reader.getSheetRows("url"); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < reader.getSheetColumns("url"); j++){
            obj[i][j] = reader.getCellData("url", j, i);
        }
    }

    return obj;
}
```

The issue is that the methods are saying that I am passing an incorrect number of arguments

```
@Test (dataProvider="testData")
public void test1(String url)
{}
```

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments

Comment: Could you share the full stacktrace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `@DataProvider` annotated data provider AFAIK, is not capable of reading parameters via the `@Parameters` annotation.

You should instead be doing it as below :

```
@DataProvider(parallel = true)
public Object[][] testData(ITestContext context) {
    //Here We are trying to read the value of
    // <parameter name="dev" value="true"/> 
    //from the suite xml file.
    String dev = context.getCurrentXmlTest().getAllParameters().get("dev");
    String path;
    if (dev.equals("true")) {
        path = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\data\\dev-data.xlsx";
    } else {
        path = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\data\\reg-data.xlsx";
    }
    //Rest of the data provider code goes here.
    return new Object[][] {{}};
}
```

Comment: Great solution! I ended up implementing a workaround. Instead of creating two xlsx files there are instead two .xml files (dev and qa) the parameter determines what URL is written to the xlsx file. This allows the developers to set their own test setup via the second xml while not having to maintain two similar xlsx files. I will keep this solution as a backup though. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should have only one column in your document.

Comment: There is only one column in the excel documents

Comment: Are you sure? Any editing can lead to creation of column. Even you changed with of some column. I suggest replace `reader.getSheetColumns("url")` by `1` in both places,

Comment: Object[][] obj = new Object[1][1];
return obj; works but when i try and utilize the dev parameter it fails

Comment: I never worked with `@Parameters`, so can't help you.

Comment: No problem. I may have found a potential workaround.